# npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs, nvm

I'm new here. I am getting an - **npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID** (details below), and I am currently running the following:

- nvm 0.32.1
- npm 2.15.9
- node v4.5.0
- grunt-cli v1.2.0
- grunt v0.4.5

And, when doing a package or I guess a module upgrade I am getting the following error...

---

```
ERR! Linux 3.16.0-30-generic
npm ERR! argv "/home/i839211/.nvm/versions/node/v4.5.0/bin/node" "/home/i839211/.nvm/versions/node/v4.5.0/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node
 v4.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! 
code EPEERINVALID

npm
 ERR! peerinvalid The package grunt@1.0.1 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!

npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer adapt-grunt-tracking-ids@0.1.2 wants grunt@~0.4.1
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer jit-grunt@0.10.0 wants grunt@>=0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-requirejs@0.4.4 wants grunt@~0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-requirejs-bundle@0.0.9 wants grunt@~0.4.1
npm 
ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-concat@0.5.1 wants grunt@>=0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-connect@1.0.2 wants grunt@>=0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-clean@1.0.0 wants grunt@>= 0.4.5
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-jshint@1.0.0 wants grunt@>=0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-less@0.11.4 wants grunt@~0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-concurrent@2.3.1 wants grunt@>=0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-bower-requirejs@1.1.1 wants grunt@>=0.4.0

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/i839211/devfs/adapt_authoring/temp/5638fb3f72f5f640912dc44b/adapt_framework/npm-debug.log

ERROR: 1
```

---

I am confused as to what to do because my version of grunt is >= the version it's asking for. I have done the following:

- npm cache clean
- rm node_modules
- re-install node/npm via nvm

I am using nvm, but I did have an issue previously with npm not being found and I did an update not using nvm. Since that time I did try to clean things up and re-install with nvm - not sure if this is presenting a problem. Any assistance/advice here would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing this ERR! condition while running npm install under RHEL8.9. I believe this error occurs when multiple versions of NPM and their dependencies are installed under the same environment. Yes, I did clean my NPM cache and remove my node modules.

Comment: Some else had this idea but it worked for me: npm clean cache

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).